# How to change the category page title in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress, this is my [site](http://www.tokotasonline.net/) and when I click on a category,it brings me up a page with all posts from that category.But I want to change the title "Category archive : ". Is that possible?If not,can I delete that text? Thank you!

Comment: It's possible, what you should add the files that you have in you theme's folder

Comment: @Tomas Cot ... What should i do with category files? Can you explain in detail? Sorry I am new to php and WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your category page Eg: in twentythirteen it is like category.php. In this page the page title is defined like this.

```
 <?php printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'twentythirteen' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) ); ?>
```

Change the title manually here. Depends on the custom theme the file name and the location is changes.

If the changes needs in  archive page. Find the archive.php and edit the title.

Comment: sorry, if I have more than one category, how to customize it automatically?

Comment: @Angkong Now the page title is showing like this. Category Archives: Category name right. How exactly you need the title ??

Comment: Create unique headlines for each different category pages, such plugin [WP Custom Category Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-category-pages/), but this plugin doesn't work :-(